# How to draw a piece of sphere

Tags: cinema4d

I tried to draw the piece of the sphere between two given meridians.

I used Boole to intersects two hemi-spheres. It does not work, since hemispheres are just polyhedrons and after rotation, they does not intersects.

Comment: I appreciate your vote of confidence; typically we *tend* to wait 24 hours before accepting an answer just in case a better one shows up after that first one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a section of sphere `"between two meridians"` I myself would set up a boolean (Boole in C4D) intersecting a slender rectangle with a complete sphere, keeping the intersecting area. I wouldn't play around with two hemispheres at all.

[image]